# Rendering of html button in ipad

Tags: css, html, ipad, responsive-design

I am building a responsive site and I ran into this issue with ipad. The submit buttons I have are rendered differently in ipad.

The issue I have so far are:

1. Buttons have lot more radius in ipad than in other devices. I fixed it by adding

   -webkit-appearance: none;
2. The buttons are shorter than they are in other devices. As seen in the image, the orange button is truncated. I haven't been able to figure out a fix for it. Is there a way I can fix it?

[image]

CSS:

```
.button{
-moz-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
 border-radius:10px;
 border: none;
 display:inline-block;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#fff;
 font-size:18px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 padding:0 24px;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.try.button{
background-color:#fc6a06;
width:120px;
}
.buy.button{
background-color:#79c14d;
width:100px;
}
```

I could fix it by increasing the button width. But the issue I am facing is button width of 150px is smaller than the button with 150px on android tab.

Comment: try adding `-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;`

Comment: Thanks! But its not helping.

Comment: <button type="submit"> or <input type="submit"/> try the button type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

150px is 150px, no matter what.

My guess is your font size is changing, from the sample code, it was not provided. Try defining and using a web-safe font with a predetermined size.

For example, try defining

```
.button {
font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
font-size: 18px;
...
}
```

Comment: I understand. But the button's width is much more in all devices as compared to the width in iPad.

I tried with web safe font, but it didn't help. I would post in on jsfiddle, but, it doesn't replicate the behavior. I tried it on responsinator and even there it doesn't behave this way.

Comment: try setting a `width: 100px;`, `min-width: 100px;` or a `max-width: 100px;` to the `.button`

Comment: @user3861559 - so a fiddle viewed in iPad wouldn't replicate it? That doesn't make any sense. Are you using inputs or buttons?